# Would search engines consider footer links to my other websites to be toxic?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks, footer

I have a bunch of websites with recipes from around the world. On the footer of each one of them there are links to the others.

I was wondering if this technique is good or not for SEO. I own all of the websites and Google knows about it (they all are in Google Webmasters).

Also, having the backlink in the footer means that it is in literally every single page. Does that affect as well? Is it better to have a backlink just in one or two pages?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it would be a good idea to get backlinks from footer section. It's not a good practice in SEO. Backlinks are more strong when they are connected through your content not just sticking in footer with one anchor link and generating lots of backlinks. 
I don't think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it has any SEO effect, but it might be useful for the people that visit your site(s). For that reason alone I wouldn't discourage the practice. There are, after all, a huge audience of actual people who visit web sites as opposed to just search engines stopping by.

Here's an [example of someone loading the footer with related site links](https://www.marthastewart.com/) although each of the "partner" sites seem to have their own "footer formula". Interestingly, some of the links are broken, so maybe it's not such a useful example....

Answer (score 1):

It won't be toxic for your websites but it won't do any good as well. Google gives value to backlink in decreasing order of their location on the webpage. So a link on the first paragraph is worth a lot more than one at the last. [Source.](https://neilpatel.com/blog/backlinks-effectiveness-page-location/)

And the links on the footer get the least value.

On the contrary, it might feel spammy(just my opinion) to google if all websites point to one another from the same location on the footer.

Comment: As evidence that it probably won't hurt, look at the footer of this page.   Stack Exchange uses footer links to tie together all their web properties.   I agree that it shouldn't help these days though.   Footer links are pretty dead from an SEO standpoint.